# Print output result on same page

Tags: php, output

```
<?php
    class myDemo
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            return strip_tags(file_get_contents("http://example.com/bitcoin/checker.php?method=gLink&secret=xxxxxx&user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']));
        }
    }
    $o = new myDemo;
    $data = $o->__construct();
    $data = json_decode($data);
    echo $data->random; ?>
```

this script show to user a bitcoin address for submit payment . i want the code that make a button and when user click on the button he get bitcoin address on same page below the button . i mean user get the output of this script on same page after click on the button .

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where are you stuck? Where exactly did your attempts fail?

Comment: when i put this code the page show the output text on page without clicking button . i want that when user click on the button after that the page show output text on same page .

Answer (score 0):

You may implement an AJAX request to do that.

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="getBitCoinAddr" value="Get Address"> 
<div id="BitCoinAddr"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$("getBitCoinAddr").click(function(){ 
    $("#BitCoinAddr").load("BitCoinAddr.php?getResult=1");
});
```

PHP

```
if($_GET['getResult==1'])
{
    return $data->random;
}
```

However, it's better to separate side effects and declarations (PSR-1).